# How do I run a private CPAN server?

Tags: windows, perl, cpan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a local CPAN mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695/how-do-i-set-up-a-local-cpan-mirror)

Due to company security issues I'm forced into looking into a private CPAN server. Due to even more company bullshit I am forced to run it on a Windows machine. (Don't ask.)

I wasted this afternoon fiddling with cpansite and MyCPAN::App::DPAN and as of now am thoroughly frustrated by how none of that seems to work right.

Thus I am turning to you, Stackoverflow.

How can i set up a CPAN server on my own machine, accessible by network, onto which i can copy private distributions and subsequently install them on various client machines straight via CPAN. How does your workflow look like?

**Please do refrain from suggesting modules unless you've actually used them and can describe how to use them.**

Comment: Can you run an FTP daemon on the machine, and can other machines FTP to it?

Comment: Yep, that's perfectly fine. I can install anything one can install on a normal windows machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a local CPAN mirror?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695/how-do-i-setup-a-local-cpan-mirror) -- see specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695/how-do-i-set-up-a-local-cpan-mirror/109447#109447) which describes [CPAN::Mini::Inject](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::Mini::Inject).

Comment: Yes, thank you, that answer is perfect. Especially the talk it contains. :D

Comment: You earned an upvote with that second sentence. :-)